# How to fetch tiktok ads data using python

Tags: python, python-3.x, tiktok, tiktok-api

I need to fetch data from tiktok for Campaign, Ad Group and Ad,
this is what I tried

```
import requests

url = "https://business-api.tiktok.com/open_api/v1.3/campaign/get/"

access_token = "your_access_token"

headers = {
    "Authorization": f"Bearer {access_token}"
}

response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)

if response.status_code == 200:
    print(response.json()) 
else:
    print(f"Failed to fetch ad campaigns. Status code: {response.status_code}")
    print(None)
```

But this is giving error as below

```
{'code': 40104, 'message': 'Access token is null, you should set it in http header with key Access-Token.', 'request_id': '', 'data': {}}
```

Comment: I'm sorry, but did you read the error message?

Comment: Where the error message says `Access token is null, you should set it in http header with key Access-Token.`, what do you think this means? In particular, what do you suppose the `with key Access-Token` part might be trying to tell you about the header? Aside from that, did you try reading the documentation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your header is wrong (as it also says in the error), it has to be:

```
headers = {
    "Access-Token": "your_access_token"
}
```

Official documentation: https://ads.tiktok.com/marketing_api/docs?id=1739315828649986

Comment: @gourav In your TikTok business account, go to Users > Members, and under the Advertiser account, you can see the ID.